# Understanding Wittgenstein's proof of Infinitude of prime

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers, analytic-number-theory, prime-gaps

Can someone please tell me why the last claim "It is thus the case..." is true?

I tried considering negation of the last claim. But it didn't help.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The product on the right consists of the sum of $\frac 1n$ where $n$ is any number divisible only by the primes $≤m$.  These numbers may occur with some multiplicity, that doesn't matter.  It is also easy to see that the product on the right is $$\frac 2{2-1}\times \frac 3{3-1}\times \cdots \times \frac m{m-1}=m$$

Thus, if every natural number from $1$ to $4^m$ factored completely using the primes $≤m$ we'd have that the left hand sum was $≤ m$ contrary to the stated premise.

Comment: Can you explain the last line a little more?

Comment: Suppose that every natural number $n\in \{1,\cdots, 4^m\}$ factored completely in primes $≤m$.  Then $\frac 1n$  would appear on the right hand, possibly more than once. It would then follow that every term in the left hand sum appeared in the right hand, so the left hand would be $≤ m$.

Comment: Got it.thanks...